# How to get touch position?

Tags: android, xamarin, pdfnet

i want to use PDFNet to read and create some overlay image on top of PDF like marker on map. I don't know how to get touch position on PDF and how re-calculate that position then i make a move or zoom. Please tell me the way. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the touch position start with PreToolManagerListener.onSingleTapConfirmed method in ToolManager.java file. Once you have the touch position, which will be in screen coordinates, you would call PDFViewCtrl.convScreenPtToPagePt To get the coordinates in the particular PDF page. From there you can match up the page coordinates with your map marker.

PDFViewCtrl.convScreenPtToPagePt will handle all page transformations, including layout, zoom, position, rotation, etc.

Comment: Thank you. But i have an issue. I used PDFNet for my xamarin project. And i want handle event when i move, zoom. But i only have  onMove, onScaleBegin listener in PdfViewCtrlTool. Where can i find onScrollChanged and onScale.

Comment: onScrollChanged and onScale are not currently "exposed". However, as we do provide the source code for customization, you could expose these by following how the same pattern as onMove/onScaleBegin are done.